# Is there any phase or frequency impairements caused by different sampling frequency at transmitter and receiver?

Tags: ofdm

I have an OFDM Tx Rx chain with different sampling rates at the Transmitter and Receiver with the same center frequency used for transmission and reception. I understand that different center frequencies at the Tx and Rx cause CFO and SFO but I need to check the case for the same Tx and Rx center frequency with different sampling rates at Tx and Rx.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you think "SFO" stands for! No, that does *not* happen due to a carrier frequency offset.

Comment: Sampling frequency offset and carrier frequency offset can both have the same reason and be proportional to each other, if the hardware on both sides was designed that way, but it's not generally the case.